# Ubuntu 12.10 update didn't go well, OS is messed app

Tags: 12.10, boot, upgrade, updates

I tried to update my Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. The update downloaded the needed files and then started setting up the packages. Suddenly, I saw some weird things on the screen, and then I didn't have any top or left bar. I couldn't close an app, couldn't switch between apps (alt+tab, windows key, any other shortcut didn't work).
So I made a huge mistake and restarted the computer manually.
When the computer booted, I chose to boot ubuntu, and then it told me that the file drive in /tmp wasn't ready to use and I should press S to skip or M to boot manually, I pressed S but nothing happened, so yet again I did another restart and this time I chose to boot recovery mode. I chose to repair packages (Something like this, I don't remember exactly), and it started going over all my packages.
After it finished, I boot again and I hash a working OS (12.10) but the screen resolution wasn't good, so I logged in and again, didn't have any top or left bar, only a desktop. I managed to get into the file browser and saw that all of my files are there.

How can I repair it?

[image: Login]

[image: Desktop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch, that's unfortunate :-(. If I understand you correctly, you have interrupted the installation process somewhere in the middle and then fixed it from command line by using...apt-get?

Please try the following (from console CTRL+ALT+1):

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that you can always try uninstalling Xorg (sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-core) and installing ubuntu-desktop again. It should be harmless.

**OP posted his own SOLUTION**

Ok, I've found the problem - AMD drivers. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu from USB disk, but I had the same problem again. So I did what Rostislav said, removed Xorg.

I removed Xorg and then reinstalled ubuntu 12.10 from usb again, this time it went well. So I installed all the things I needed again, and also the AMD driver.

I rebooted my computer after the installation, and again the same problem all the OS got messed up. So then I realized that this driver is what did the problem all along. So I opened a TTY session and uninstalled the driver, reinstalled the Xorg, and now it's all working well.